# Generating a string of file names, alternative to global variable?

Tags: php

I'm creating a function where users can upload multiple images and upload them to the server. Using a global variable for this matter works, but I've heard global variables are bad especially in OOP. So, I'm wondering what a good alternative would be? (I'm a starting PHP programmer, any detailed information is appreciated)

Code:

```
function addImgToNieuws($images){

    if (isset($images) && $images != "") {
        $countFiles = count($images["name"]);

        for ($i = 0; $i < $countFiles; $i++) {
            $fileName = $images["name"][$i];
            $fileType = $images["type"][$i];
            $fileSize = $images["size"][$i];
            $fileError = $images["error"][$i];
            $fileTmp = $images["tmp_name"][$i];

            $kaboom = explode(".", $fileName);
            $fileExt = end($kaboom);

            $db_file_name = rand(100000, 999999) . "." . $fileExt;
            $output = $this->db->real_escape_string($db_file_name);

            global $string;
            $string .= ",$output";
            $string = substr($string, 1);
        }

        echo $string;
    }

}
```

Comment: instead of echo, use `return $string;` no global will them be needed. also an array of file names would probably be eiser to work with - depends what you plan to do with $string

Comment: If I try that, it will either tell me string is undefined or string wont have a value.

Comment: have a look at the code answer below

Comment: That's because the first time you use `$string` you're appending with `.=` since `$string` is undefined you get that error. Define `$string = ""` at the top of your function. Also the return value of this function should be an array, not a string, since your input is also an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
function addImgToNieuws($images){

    if (isset($images) && $images != "") {
        throw new Exception("bad input bro");
    }
    $countFiles = count($images["name"]);

    $db_names = array();

    for ($i = 0; $i < $countFiles; $i++) {
        $fileName = $images["name"][$i];
        $fileType = $images["type"][$i];
        $fileSize = $images["size"][$i];
        $fileError = $images["error"][$i];
        $fileTmp = $images["tmp_name"][$i];

        $kaboom = explode(".", $fileName);
        $fileExt = end($kaboom);

        $db_file_name = rand(100000, 999999) . "." . $fileExt;
        $db_names[] = $this->db->real_escape_string($db_file_name)
    }

    return $db_names;

}
```

Assuming you wanted to get the `$db_names`. It's a little bit odd to do the escaping here, I would delay it until the very moment you insert it in the query.

If you really wanted the `$db_names` as a string you can do:

```
echo join(",", $obj->addImgToNieuws($images));
```